# Query logic to identify new and returning customers

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im trying to figure out the best way to write a query that will help me identify customers that are new this month BUT ALSO old customers that last had a transaction with us three months ago but just returned this month.

```
select customer_id
 from(
   select s.customer_id,
        min(ss.tran_date) as customer_first_date,
        max(ss.tran_date) as customer_last_date
  from shipments s
  left join shipment_stops ss on ss.customer_id = s.customer_id) 
  where date_trunc('month',customer_first_date) = date_trunc('month',now()) OR ?????
```

any help or a point to the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

thank you very much in advance.

Best,

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the most recent month, so look at the latest transaction in the `having` clause and then the earliest in the `select`:

```
select s.customer_id,
       (case when min(ss.tran_date) >= date_trunc('month', now()) 
             then 'New'
             else 'Existing'
        end) as grouping
from shipments s left join
     shipment_stops ss
     on ss.customer_id = s.customer_id 
group by s.customer_id
having max(ss.tran_date) >= date_trunc('month', now())
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this addresses my issue regarding old customers returning after three months of non transactions

Comment: @spak . . . This identifies new and existing customer *in general*.  That seems to be what your question is asking.  I interpreted the three months as an example of a returning customer.

Answer (score 0):

using subquery- picking the 3 month old customer and current month customer then done left join with 3 month old customer with current month if both customer matched then it is old customer otherwise new

```
with t1 as
    ( select s.* from from shipments s
      left join shipment_stops ss on ss.customer_id = s.customer_id)
    where date_trunc('month',customer_first_date)<= date_trunc('month',CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 months')
    ) , t2 as
 (
   select s.* from from shipments s
      left join shipment_stops ss on ss.customer_id = s.customer_id)
    where date_trunc('month',customer_first_date)>= date_trunc('month',now())
 ) select case when t2.customer_id=t1.customer_id then 'old customer'
   else 'new customer who comes this month' end customer_status
     left join t1
  on t2.customer_id =t1.customer_id
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this addresses my issue regarding old customers returning after three months of non transactions

Comment: @spak if your old customer back then he will be avail in both dataset of t1 and t2 and i ded comparison of t1 and t2

Answer (score 0):

Locate all clients with transactions this month (using an `exists` subquery) and some conditional aggregation to differentiate between new and returning:

```
SELECT
    customer_id
  , CASE
        WHEN prev_max_dt < (current_date - '3 month'::INTERVAL)
        THEN 'Returning'
        ELSE 'New'
    END
FROM (
    SELECT
        ss.customer_id
      , MAX(CASE
            WHEN ss.tran_date < date_trunc('month', current_date) THEN ss.tran_date
        END) AS prev_max_dt
    FROM shipment_stops ss
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL
        FROM shipment_stops
        WHERE tran_date >= date_trunc('month', current_date)
        AND customer_id = ss.customer_id
        )
    GROUP BY
        ss.customer_id
) d
```